# problems with btree deletion in c

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

i've been trying to implement a btree using c and i'm having some dificulties in getting the deletion correctly done and working. the code that is below compiles ok, but it does not work. i've been debugging it and trying to find out what's wrong and why it's not working and fix the issues.
so what i ask is that anyone could see the problem with it with a fresh pair of eyes and point me in the right direction.

```
btree.h file

#define BTREE_H
#define ordem 3
#define maxfilhos 2*ordem
#define maxchaves 2*ordem-1

typedef struct InfoPalavra infoPalavra;
struct InfoPalavra {
   int idPalavra;
   char palavraFicheiro[32];
};
typedef struct btree btree;

struct btree {
  int folha;
  int n;
  infoPalavra chave[maxchaves];
  //int chave[maxchaves];

  //infoPalavra *chave;
  struct btree *filho[maxfilhos];
};
#endif /* BTREE_H */
```

.

```
btree.c
void recursive_delete(btree *t)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<maxfilhos; i++)
    {
        if (t->filho[i]) {
            recursive_delete(t->filho[i]);
        }
        //if(t->filho[i]!=0)
        //recursive_delete(t->filho[i]);
    }
    free(t);
}
```

Comment: You have to post a [mcve].  What you've posted in too large an example. Also, `it does not work` is not a problem statement.

Comment: so as i'm gonna delete all the nodes on the tree. i've thought, why not delete with recursion. so i changed it a bit and now i'm struggling with a segmentation fault in the condition to check the child node. i've been testing it but it originates segmentation fault. cause the test in the recursive function goes where it should not.

Comment: When you create a node, are you initializing all child nodes to NULL?  Otherwise, your check for `t->filho[i]` will typically return `true` and then wander all over memory that doesn't belong to your process.

Comment: Looking at the original text of the question, you don't appear to be allocating any new memory.  Why are you freeing memory you haven't allocated?  And why haven't you allocated any storage for this data structure?

Comment: a c file called Utilites.c i have a static btree *tmpTree; it is initialized in a method i defined by using this nova(&tmpTree); and the actual code for the creation of the tree in a btree.c file is done like this: void nova(btree **t)
{
 *t = malloc(sizeof(**t));
 (*t)->folha=1;
 (*t)->n=0;
 //(*t)->chave=malloc((infoPalavra)*maxchaves);int i;
     for (i=0;i<maxfilhos;i++){
  (*t)->filho[i]=NULL;
 }
}

Comment: and i was trying to check for a struct member if it was null and that does not work. i've tried checking if the filho[i]->n was null and that does not work. if it's not initialized it should return false and not let me wander to a place where nothing exists.

Comment: i managed to solve it. i changed the code a bit and finally got it working. basically i check if the node is a leaf and if not iterate from 0 to the value of occupancy and call the function recursevely and free the node accordingly